# Copy emails with a specific Gmail label to Spreadsheet, without duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am trying to make a script that takes an email within a certain label and puts it into Google Sheets. I'm using this function at the moment:

```
function getMessagesWithLabel() {
 var destArray = new Array();
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Facebook').getThreads(0,10);

  for(var n in threads){
        var msg = threads[n].getMessages();
        var destArrayRow = new Array();
        destArrayRow.push('thread has '+threads[n].getMessageCount()+' messages');
          for(var m in msg){
                     destArrayRow.push(msg[m].getSubject());
           }
  destArray.push(destArrayRow);           
        }
Logger.log(destArray);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
if(ss.getLastRow()==0){sh.getRange(1,1).setValue('getMessagesWithLabel() RESULTS')};
sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,destArray.length,destArray[0].length).setValues(destArray)
}
```

This works at grabbing all the emails in the 'Facebook' label but grabs all the emails every time, creating duplicates every time it runs. I would like for it to just create a new line every time a new one is put into the 'Facebook' label.

Comment: Ok new question. What direction should i go to get the message body and date added to the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four thoughts for you to explore.

1. Use [`GmailMessage.getDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getDate()) to filter out messages you've already handled. Store the time that the script runs in [`ScriptProperties`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getScriptProperties()) and reload it as your threshold next time.
2. Every message has its own unique ID, so recording that along with the body would give you a key to look up. I think this would be slower than the first option, but could be much faster if you stored key values in `ScriptProperties`.
3. Use [`search()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)) to match label and time, again keeping track of when the script has run in `ScriptProperties`.

   ```
   var threads = GmailApp.search('label:"Facebook" after:"2015/6/1"');
   ```

   That will give *threads* with any messages added after the given date, but the threads will also have messages prior to that date. You'll probably still have to use one of the earlier options to filter those out. (Unless, as you've indicated in comments, your thread will have no replies and thus only one message.)
4. Once a thread is processed, remove the label you used to categorize it.

   ```
   var oldLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Facebook');
   var newLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Facebook-processed');
   var threads = oldLabel.getThreads(0,10);
   for(var n in threads){
     ...
     threads[n].removeLabel(oldLabel).addLabel(newLabel);
   }
   ```

Comment: Just to add more info. Every incoming email is a workorder and there are no responces. Currently i just copy the workorder into a google document where what i want to happen is for it to go to a spreadsheet where a merge script can make it into a document (I already have this part done).

Comment: Great, then option 3 should work brilliantly for you, as threads will only have one message in them. You could alternatively just remove the label after handling a message, and keep the rest of your code as-is.

Comment: how is var threads = GmailApp.search('label:"Facebook" after:"2015/6/1"'); used to filter out already exported messages?

Comment: That was an example of using the API. Replace the date with the last date you ran the script. Note, though: the granularity for gmail search parameters `after` and `before` is `day`, which stars at midnight in your account's time zone.

Comment: I am getting an error  "Cannot find method removeLabel(string)."

Comment: It's a Thread method... are you using it on a message instead?

Comment: I inserted your remove label code after destArrayRow.push('thread has '+threads[n].getMessageCount()+' messages');

Comment: Yep... label shouldn't be a string, it should be a Label object.

Comment: I dont get it. sorry im new to this and trying to understand

Comment: Updated. It'll complain if the labels don't exist: homework for you. Re the error: with service methods, you must give parameters matching the expected types. `Thread.removeLabel()`, for example, wanted one parameter, a `Label` object. I mistakenly provided a string, mirroring the behaviour of `getUserLabelByName()`. The error message says that the system could not find a method named `removeLabel` with a `String` parameter. That could be because the object it's being applied to doesn't support that method (happens often) or that the wrong parameter type was provided.